# PHP mysqli Multi Query + Transaction

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, mysqli

I have the following code:

```
...
$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);

if(in_array('files',$item)){
            $sql_el_truncate = "
                TRUNCATE TABLE `article_files`;
                TRUNCATE TABLE `files`;
                TRUNCATE TABLE `gallery_files`;
                TRUNCATE TABLE `image_captions`;
            ";

            $mysqli->multi_query($sql_el_truncate);

            do{ 
                $mysqli->use_result(); 
            }while ($mysqli->next_result()); 


            if ($mysqli->errno) { 
                $valid_entry = 0;
            } 
            echo $valid_entry;
        }

if( $valid_entry){
            $mysqli->commit();
        }else{
            $mysqli->rollback();
        }

...
```

On error I get a proper `$valid_entry` value of 0, but the rollback is not working. Even if I write on purpose some of the TRUNCATE commands falsely it will still run the rest commands, give me the error but it won't rollback.

Anyone knows how can I properly use the transaction on the `mysqli`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index.html) for [`TRUNCATE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/truncate-table.html) (emphasis is mine):

> Logically, TRUNCATE TABLE is similar to a DELETE statement that
>   deletes all rows, or a sequence of DROP TABLE and CREATE TABLE
>   statements. To achieve high performance, it bypasses the DML method of
>   deleting data. Thus, **it cannot be rolled back**, it does not cause ON
>   DELETE triggers to fire, and it cannot be performed for InnoDB tables
>   with parent-child foreign key relationships.

If you want to be able to `ROLLBACK` you are going to have to use `DELETE` statements instead.  They are less efficient here, but should give you the desired behavior.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Now what are you suggesting I did? Leave it as it is and still get some of the truncates run since they were to run anyway or there is an alternative method?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like those TRUNCATE commands cause an implicit commit:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/implicit-commit.html